# Can't seem to return a string

Tags: c

I'm trying to append two strings in C.

So this is my code, if I return s3, nothing gets printed. Yet if I return s1 or s2, they return correctly.

Also if I just hit enter on my keyboard twice it prints `"L¬(."`

In C++ I never had these kinds of problems, yikes.

Can someone please check if they see a problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
    Return the result of appending the characters in s2 to s1.
    Assumption: enough space has been allocated for s1 to store the extra
    characters.
*/
char* append (char s1[ ], char s2[ ]) {
    int s1len = strlen (s1);
    int s2len = strlen (s2);
    int s3len=strlen(s1)+strlen(s2);
   // printf("%d", s1len);
    char s3[s3len];
    int k;
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<s1len; j++) {
        s3[j]=s1[j];
    }

    for (k=0; k<s2len; k++) {
        s3[k+s1len] = s2[k];

    }

    return s3;
}

int main ( ) {
    char str1[10];
    char str2[10];
    while (1) {
        printf ("str1 = ");
        if (!gets (str1)) {
            return 0;
        };
        printf ("str2 = ");
        if (!gets (str2)) {
            return 0;
        };
        printf ("The result of appending str2 to str1 is %s.\n", 
            append (str1, str2));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A problem is, because `s3` is a local variable in `append`, the memory for `s3` is allocated in `append` and then freed when it goes out of scope (when the function ends), regardless of whether or not you return a pointer to it.

What you should do is pass `s3` as a `char *` or `char[]` as a parameter to the function.

Like this: (changing `append` should be easy enough)

```
// yes the +1 to be able to null-terminate the string is needed,
//   or just make it much bigger
char s3[strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1];
append(str1, str2, s3);
printf("The output is %s\n", s3);
```

Also remember to add a `0` as the last character of `s3` in `append` as ogzd suggested (null-terminate the string).

Alternatives:

- (C++) Return `std::string` (a bit slower because the memory is copied)
- Do a `malloc` (C/C++) or `new` (C++) in `append` to allocate the memory for `s3`. This is a dangerous practice since the memory must be `free`'d or `delete`'d respectively.

With `malloc`, literally the only thing you'll need to change is the definition of `s3` in your function, to:

```
char *s3 = malloc(s3len+1);
```

Normally you'd say:

```
type *s3 = malloc(sizeof(type)*len);
```

But `char` is 1 byte, so `sizeof(char) = 1`.

Comment: or better, return an std::string.

Comment: how would i return a std::string?

Comment: @user2054534 Just to clarify, are you doing C or C++? `std::string` is C++

Comment: c, sorry I should have clarified.

Comment: @Dukeling, C++11 should support move semantics so it does not necessarily require any memory copying.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the `\0` character at the end of `s3`!

```
char s3[s3len+1];
......

s3[s3len] = 0; // \0 character
```

Comment: Also, don't return the address of stack-based variables ;P

Answer (score 1):

instead of return the local variable s3

return an allocated copy of it :

```
return strdup(s3);
```

just make sure you free the memory returned once you are done with it.

also make sure you 0 terminate your strings, this is essential in C since that is the only thing that distinguishes a string from an array. functions that take a string argument assume an ending 0 is in the character sequence.

Comment: thank you, this worked great. I also had to terminal the string as mentioned earlier. How would I do the same thing with malloc for curiosity?

Comment: e.g. `char *buf = malloc( strlen( s3 ) + 1 ); strcpy( buf, s3 ); return buf;`

Comment: @user2054534 You just need to change the definition of `s3` if you want to use `malloc`, as per the edit to my answer.